# pyspark: Is it possible to enable logging information in CrossValidation?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib, cross-validation

While using CrossValidation estimator in pyspark I would like to print the satuts of the cross validation as well as I used to to in scikit-learn.

For example the GridSerch object in scikit-learn allow you to set the verbose level, so the execution inform you about which parameter combination has been already tested and what is the performance of each job.

Comment: I think you can extend the `CrossValidator()` class, creating your own custom Cross Validator class to print out the loggings. Check this nice article: https://www.timlrx.com/2018/04/08/creating-a-custom-cross-validation-function-in-pyspark/
    
Inside the `CrossValidator()` class there's a method called `_fit()`. You can simple add logs between the lines.